# DocuSign Connect webhook to call a WCF Rest service endpoint

Tags: asp.net, wcf, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm having an issue with DocuSign Connect hitting our WCF endpoint.

We have the following WCF endpoint which accepts a Stream parameter.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/PBSAPI")]
Stream PBSAPI(Stream data);
```

DocuSign Connect webhook sends JSON to our endpoint, but the headers Content-Type is set to application/json.

Because we are accepting a Stream parameter the header content type must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

We are using "per-envelope" webhooks. Is it possible to configure the eventNotification object to specify the content-type to use? Similar to passing custom_fields in the webhook body?

I've tried using a different parameter such as string to accept the payload, but it does not seem to work when content-type = application/json.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to configure the eventNotification object to specify the content-type to use?

No. DocuSign Connect specifically sends only "application/Json". DocuSign Connect is mainly used for sending status updates on envelopes (which is done as a JSON).

If you have a specific use-case you're looking to implement, please reach out to DocuSign support to discuss this further.

Answer (score 0):

Today, DocuSign webhooks are only sent as JSON. Previously they were sent as JSON or XML.

You can create your own serverless function from [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/lambda/), Azure or other suppliers to transform the JSON to form-encoded. However, you'll need to create a mapping table since JSON is a richer format (it includes objects (associative arrays)) and form-encoded format does not.

Comment: My other alternative would be to create an object data contract that would represent the JSON. I can then use that object as the accepted parameter. Once a request comes in, the JSON would be deserialized/materialized into that object. My only concern is if the JSON is always the same structure/format for all requests? I realize WCF is an older technology, but does DocuSign have any samples that use WCF?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have any WCF examples. Please consider making yours open source for others